# How do I test a heater core [before installing it]?

Tags: heater-core

The one went out in my car and I installed a Spectra Premium from CarId that leaked all over my floor.  The limited lifetime warranty advertised did not apply to the item advertised, so I ordered the same one from AutoZone, which just says "Limited lifetime," without three paragraphs that end with "Spectra Premium Radiators, Condensers, Heater Cores and Ignition Distributors have no warranty."
I just want to make sure that it is good before I install it, I don't want to be doing this a third time [and potentially fourth and fifth]!
I trimmed down a Schrader valve to fit in one hole, clamped it in-place, inserted a rubber plug into the other hole, and used a bike pump to pressurize the heater core to 16 PSI, which is the cooling system's rating.  The air leaked out within a few minutes, although I never heard any hissing.
Is the problem with the heater core or my rig?
Oh!  How do I remove a rubber stopper from a hole?!  My rig pushed it almost all of the way in!  I don't want to put a hole in it!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have pressurized it, immerse it in the bath to see where any leaks are, just like doing a bicycle inner tube repair.

I would also keep the air supply connected so you get a constant stream of bubbles if there is a leak.

Make a handle for the stopper before you get it stuck, now you need to drill a hole deep enough to put as screw in it, without going all the way through.

Comment: The heater core fins trap a great deal of air and I would be unable to distinguish leaking air from bubbles just trapped by the fins.

Comment: @MenloPart just too challenging sometimes.